# Turns pandas.df into this specific JSON format

Tags: json, pandas

Consider this pandas dataframe:

```
This_df = pandas.DataFrame({'SYM': {0: 'this_string', 1: 'this_string', 2: 'this_string'},
 'DATE': {0: 'NaN', 1: 'NaN', 2: 'NaN'},
 'YEST': {0: 'NaN', 1: 'NaN', 2: 'NaN'},
 'other_DATE': {0: 'NaN', 1: 'NaN', 2: 'NaN'},
 'SIZE': {0: 'NaN', 1: 'NaN', 2: 'NaN'},
 'ACTIVITY': {0: '2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC',
  1: '2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC',
  2: '2019-09-27 14:18:28.000600 UTC'}})
```

I'm trying to save it in a file, in such a way that the content of the file looks like this:

```
'{"SYM": ["this_string","this_string","this_string"],"DATE": ["NaN","NaN","NaN"],"YEST": ["NaN","NaN","NaN"],"other_DATE": ["NaN","NaN","NaN"],"SIZE": ["NaN","NaN","NaN"],"ACTIVITY": ["2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC","2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC","2019-09-27 14:18:28.000600 UTC"]}'
```

but doing:

```
pandas.DataFrame(This_df).to_json(orient = 'columns')
```

returns:

```
'{"SYM":{"0":"this_string","1":"this_string","2":"this_string"},"DATE":{"0":"NaN","1":"NaN","2":"NaN"},"YEST":{"0":"NaN","1":"NaN","2":"NaN"},"other_DATE":{"0":"NaN","1":"NaN","2":"NaN"},"SIZE":{"0":"NaN","1":"NaN","2":"NaN"},"ACTIVITY":{"0":"2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC","1":"2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC","2":"2019-09-27 14:18:28.000600 UTC"}}'
```

any ideas how to turn these inner curly braces into squared ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turns pandas.df into this specific JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499012/turns-pandas-df-into-this-specific-json-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to dictionaries and then to json, because `to_json(orient = 'list')` is not implemented:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(This_df)

j = json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient = 'list'))
print (j)

{"SYM": ["this_string", "this_string", "this_string"], "DATE": ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN"], "YEST": ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN"], "other_DATE": ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN"], "SIZE": ["NaN", "NaN", "NaN"], "ACTIVITY": ["2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC", "2019-09-27 14:18:28.000700 UTC", "2019-09-27 14:18:28.000600 UTC"]}
```

Comment: why do you need to call `pd.DataFrame`? for me it works without (assuming that `This_df` is already a data frame. Great answer as always

Comment: @Datanovice - I think it is sample data only